# (CeontOS) How to respawn lighttpd & MySQL in "/etc/inittab"

Tags: lighttpd, inittab

I need to manually create auto-respawning for lighttpd & MySQL to make sure it running all time

But what is the code to put in `/etc/inittab`?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I hate myself for saying this, but have you looked at daemontools by DJB? ( http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html ) They do what you want. But why do you want to do it like that?

Are you having some sort of problem where your daemons die? Can't we fix the problem, rather than continually respawn them?

Comment: +1 for medicating, not band-aid.